# XSLT: parse XML and re-structure XML?

Tags: xslt

I want to tranform the following XML:

```
<root>
  <ParaList>
    <Para name="p001" label="Continuous1" />
    <Para name="p002" label="Continuous5" />
    <Para name="p003" label="[Categorical3=1]" />
    <Para name="p004" label="[Categorical3=2]" />
    <Para name="p005" label="[Categorical3=3]" />
  </ParaList>

  <ParaMatrix>
    <PCell paraName="p001" coef="1.043"/>
    <PCell paraName="p002" coef="0.841"/>
    <PCell paraName="p003" coef="0.907"/>
    <PCell paraName="p004" coef="-0.26"/>
    <PCell paraName="p005" coef="5.333"/>
  </ParaMatrix>
</root>
```

into a new XML:

```
<root>
  <PMatrix>
    <NumericCell paraName="Continuous1" coef="1.043"/>
    <NumericCell paraName="Continuous5" coef="0.841"/>
    <CategoricalCell value="1" paraName="Categorical3" coef="0.907"/>
    <CategoricalCell value="2" paraName="Categorical3" coef="-0.26"/>
    <CategoricalCell value="3" paraName="Categorical3" coef="5.333"/>
  </PMatrix>
</root>
```

In the original XML, there are 3 variables Continous1,Continuous5,Categorical3. Continous1 & Continuous5 are continuous numeric values, Categorical3 is categorical with 3 possible values (1,2,3) which are treated as 3 separate parameters (p003, p004, p005). Each parameter has a coefficient. 
There could be more variables, and they don`t follow any naming convension. You can only tell some are categorical because *label="[categoricalVariableName=value]"* . Each categorical variable, if it has M possible values, M number of parameters are generated.

I want to parse the original XML, get the direct mapping of coef(coefficient) to the variable, not the paramters. If it is a continuous variable,

```
<NumericCell paraName="Continuous1" coef="1.043"/>
```

If it is a categorical variable,

```
<CategoricalCell value="1" paraName="Categorical3" coef="0.907"/>
<CategoricalCell value="2" paraName="Categorical3" coef="-0.26"/>
<CategoricalCell value="3" paraName="Categorical3" coef="5.333"/>
```

I am using XSLT version 1.0. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What version of XSLT? What have you tried?

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Will there always be exactly 5 `Para` elements in the input?

Comment: I have re-written my original question. I am using XSLT version 1.0. I did not try much, because I don`t know how to do this. Th

Comment: It's impossible to figure out what in your input is given - and can be relied upon by the processing code - and what's just an example and could change from case to case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question leaves room for a lot of guesswork, and your sample output isn't even well-formed, but let's suppose what you want is this: for each ParaList/Para Z, generate a child of PMatrix as follows: if Z/@label has the form pN, generate a  with @paraName equal to Z/@label, and coef taken from the corresponding PCell. If Z/@label has the form [pN=M], generate a  with value=M, paraName=pN, and coef as above.

This leaves a lot of cases unanswered, for example where the label doesn't match either of these patterns. But this would give something like this:

```
<xsl:key name="cell" match="ParaMatrix/PCell" use="@paraName"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
   <PMatrix>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="root/ParaList/Para"/>
   </PMatrix>
  </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Para[matches(@label, 'p[0-9]')">
  <NumericCell paraName="{@label}" coef="{key('cell', @name)/@coef}"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Para[matches(@label, '\[p[0-9]=[0-9]+\]')]">
  <CategoricalCell coef="{key('cell', @name)/@coef}">
   <xsl:analyze-string select="@label" regex="\[(p[0-9])=([0-9]+)\]">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
     <xsl:attribute name="value" select="regex-group(2)"/>
     <xsl:attribute name="paraName" select="regex-group(1)"/>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring/>
   </xsl:analyze-string>
  </CategoricalCell> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hello Michael, thanks for your comments. I realised my question was not clear in some aspects. So I have re-written my question. The names of the variables (out of these variables => parameters) do not follow any naming convention. Thanks a lot for your expertise.

Comment: Then just replace the regular expressions in my example with more liberal ones, e.g. p[0-9] becomes [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*.

Comment: Hello Michael, I tried your code, but got syntax error, "unknown function 'matches'. Is this because I am using xsl version 1.0? Could you please help me with a solution for 1.0? Thank you so much

Comment: Yes, matches() needs XSLT 2.0. And no, sorry, I have no interest in solving problems using XSLT 1.0 when they are vastly easier using XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Hi Michael, I have figured out the syntax with XSLT1.0, although not very elegant. I want to thank you, especially for the 'xsl:key' function which helped solve my biggest problem. Thank you.